# Travel Agency Software

Tags: online-resources, software

Is there a web based or web integrated software available for travel agents that does the following:
Lets you book rooms in a number of hotels,
Book bike and/or car rentals,
Book other extras,
Book other activities for people like like active holidays,
and can it all be done on one screen with one final bill to pay at the end?

I'm having trouble making sense of what some of the systems I've seen do.
Many thanks
Chris

Comment: That doesn't sound like software _for_ travel agents, but software that _is_ a travel agent ... if a travel agent had software to do all that slickly and easily, then which value would _he himself_ add for his customers?

Comment: Yes, Amadeus, Sabre, etc all do this. However, this is not really a travel question, it is a "how do I start a travel business" question. @HenningMakholm Probably none.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about CRS software used by travel agents, not a question aimed at helping a traveller.

Comment: There's a software recs stack exchange this seems better suited for.